# Discord.py music bot can't leave when requested, missing manage server perms

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py

I'm working on a discord bot in python, and I have made a music function for it that works pretty well. However, when I try to give the bot the "leave" command as an "everyone" user on my alt, it tells me that I am missing the "Manage Server" permissions to run the command to stop and leave. Any way I can fix this?

Part 1 of stop and leave command:

```
        self.songs.clear()

        if self.voice:
            await self.voice.disconnect()
            self.voice = None
```

Part 2

```
    @commands.command(name='leave', aliases=['disconnect'])
    @commands.has_permissions(manage_guild=True)
    async def _leave(self, ctx: commands.Context):
        """Clears the queue and leaves the voice channel."""

        if not ctx.voice_state.voice:
            return await ctx.send('Join a VC or I will spank you.')

        await ctx.voice_state.stop()
        del self.voice_states[ctx.guild.id]
```

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I seem to have fixed it, the line

```
    @commands.has_permissions(manage_guild=True)
```

had to be removed since only people with the permissions could get the bot to leave. I guess instead of requiring permission, a voting system could be a better way to prevent people from messing in VCs.